# Use of unresolved identifier when working with dictionaries on swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm having issues with **Swift 2**. Some code **used to work perfectly with previous versions of Swift**, but since Swift 2 it started to fail.

I'm using the following lines to get data from an external source, parse it with **SwiftyJSON** and then loop thought the result to do some stuff and print them in the screen.

```
            // get data
            let json = JSON(data: externalData)

            for (index: String, obj: JSON) in json {

                // put data into variables
                let a = obj["a"].stringValue
                let b = functionA(obj["b"].stringValue)
                let c = functionB(obj["c"].intValue)

                // parse a,b and c on the screen.
           }
```

The code looks like that, it was simplified, but it would be the same.

And for **each of these lines**:

```
            let a = obj["a"].stringValue
            let b = functionA(obj["b"].stringValue)
            let c = functionB(obj["c"].intValue)
```

I'm getting this **error**:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'obj'

I had look around and I couldn't find any answer for this. I hope someone can help me figure this out, I have been stuck for hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing the internal and external naming of parameters

```
for (index: String, obj: JSON) in json {
   let a = JSON["a"].stringValue
   let b = functionA(JSON["b"].stringValue)
   let c = functionB(JSON["c"].intValue)
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I dunno how it was working before. Anyway I tried a different approach, cause I was having some other issues. Thanks for your answer, you helped me a lot. This is my change: for (_, obj) in json {